# Why was the spaceship named such in Sunshine movie?

Tags: sunshine

In Sunshine (2007) movie the spaceships were named Icarus I and Icarus II , but Icarus was the first person who tried to go to Sun and died in the process. Why name a spaceship in such a way which is ill fated .

Comment: SInce they weren't crediting Clark Ashton Smith they probably did not want to go with "Phoenix", which would have made more sense, but is the name of a CAS story about an attempt to rekindle the sun with bombs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [**this source**](https://filmschoolrejects.com/commentary-sunshine-danny-boyle-2f6e52d4de91/) there is a comment in the DVD commentary

> They were asked why the ship is called Icarus, and he says the original script included dialogue meant “to remind Earth and the people on the mission of their humanity and their humility.”

Comment: How does the story of Icarus tells about humanity and humility

Comment: That is the whole story of Greek myth of Icarus. [His pride caused him to fly to close to the Sun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icarus). Using the *name* Icarus is meant as a warning...and probably a foreshadowing.

Comment: I know the story of Icarus but how does it give the message of humanity.

Comment: @codeczar - https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/1664/what-is-the-moral-of-the-myth-of-icarus